# Need a way to connect to a webservice

Tags: plugins, services

I have a lot of data that sits outside of Craft (the data is in MS SQL Server) and I plan on writing a simple .NET Service which will return JSON. I need to display this data but not sure on how to connect to a service using Craft CMS.

Are there any clients (plugins) which will connect to a service get the JSON data and display it?

Answer (score 2):

Craft 2.x includes [Guzzle 3](https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/index.html) natively, so you could write a [Craft plugin](http://pluginfactory.io) that uses it to consume your web service.

There are plenty of examples in the [Guzzle 3 docs](https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/docs.html) on how to do that (as well as in Craft itself).

You could also use something like this: https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/guzzle

Which is a wrapper for Craft's Guzzle 3 you can use from a template.

Comment: This is super cool, didn't know that someone had exposed Guzzle to the template layer! Brad's suggestion to use a plugin (with controllers + services) is really solid—it's a great architecture. Most any Twig plugin that you might use to make an HTTP request will follow that pattern behind-the-scenes.